# Drinking cold vs hot water

Tags: water

Since I started my new job about 1,5months ago, I've been conveniently located near the water cooler. This means, that I get plenty of water. Waaay more than 8 glasses per day. And now here's my question:

#### Should I be drinking hot or cold water?

Kris Gethin suggested drinking cold water, since that makes your body spend more energy on heating the water up, thus creating a bit more of a calorie deficiency while dieting.

On the other hand, I've read a couple of articles online, that suggest, that drinking hot water somehow helps purify the body, and helps one to stay awake.

Which of these should I drink and why?

Comment: Is this really on-topic here?

Comment: @VPeric The title does say Fitness and **Nutrition**. And since this also may have impact on ones diet, I do believe that it is.

Comment: With water generally being very important for both fitness and wellbeing, and drinking cold water being suggested as a fitness regime, I agree that it is on topic.

Comment: @ Janis, @Letharion, I don't really care enough to push it, but do consider that the title isn't the only important thing: if you check the FAQ you will see only nutrition *as it relates to exercise* is accepted. In that context, the temperature of the water you drink is fairly irrelevant. There's been a lot of discussions about the scope of the site, I'm sure you could find some on Meta if you want to. Anyway, it hardly matters.

Comment: Well if anyone wants to answer this in comments, I'd give your comment an upvote!